# JSDoc: assign type to inline variable

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

Can I assign a type to a variable which gets a `object` result from a third party library?

```
const result = thirdPartyLib.doSomething();
```

Now I may have a ES6 class

```
class MyClass {
  ...
}
```

And I want to annotate my `result` to be of type `MyClass`.

Is this possible using JSDoc?

Comment: Are you using Typescript? If not I wouldn't worry about its type.

Comment: In theory, yes, you can put a `@type` on it, but the way different JSDoc annotations are handled by different tools can vary a lot, so it's hard to provide a useful answer without knowing what you're doing with this/what tool you're using/what result you expect.

Comment: I’m using WebStorm and I want to annotate the type for better code completion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The JSDoc [`@type {…}` tag](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html) can be applied to a local variable to declare its type.

```javascript
/** @type {MyClass} */
const result = thirdPartyLib.doSomething();
```

[image: screenshot of WebStorm editor showing type-driven autocompletions after adding this tag]

However, instead of adding this declaration everywhere you call the function, you could use the [`@external` tag](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-external.html) to add JSDoc types to `thirdPartyLib.doSomething()`, allowing the local variable types to be inferred correctly.

```javascript
/**
 * @external thirdPartyLib
 */
/**
 * @function external:thirdPartyLib.doSomething
 * @returns {MyClass}
 */

const result = thirdPartyLib.doSomething();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how would that work using a third party library like `Joi` which returns a result like this `const {err,result} = Joi.validate(...)`. I want to be `result` to be of type `MyClass`.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler I think you can use the "record type" syntax in the external definition: `@returns {{result: ?MyClass, err: ?Error}}`. The question marks before the type names indicate that they're nullable (I'm assuming that result is null if error is set, and vice-versa). I don't have PyCharm here to verify that it supports this properly, but it should.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler Seems to work here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c3qv.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gaufs.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuJyp.png

Comment: Is it possible it works for you because `thirdPartyLib.doSomething()` is defined by you and WebStorm infers the types from there?